# How do you trade with merchants?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

At first I thought pressing "o" would conclude the trading, been doing this for multiple games. Well in my pursuit to find out why I was losing items and not gaining anything from the caravans I checked the wiki. It explains how it works but it doesn't seem to explain how to conclude your transaction. What am I missing? **How do I conclude my trade with the caravans?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're picking offer, not trade, essentially giving them gifts to increase your favor with them. To propose the trade, pick <kbd>t</kbd>.

Comment: yes i understand that part, but what happens after that?

Comment: @Paralytic: Then the goods are exchanged, they reject the trade, or they propose a different trade.

Comment: Then you hit `esc` and continue playing with magma.

Comment: @authenticgeek yah i did exactly that, and nothing happened. still have all the stuff i tried to trade.

Comment: There should have been a message whether they accept or reject the trade, either way. Also, there should be the merchant's mood shown on top.

Comment: @ShiDoiSi Yah just realized after i said that, that i was using masterwork mod at the time and you actually have to hit "t" to finish a trade.